# Debugging tcl crash on windows

Tags: windows, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, pyinstaller

I have a Tkinter application that sometimes crashes under Windows. The error is a generic 'program has stopped working and needs to close'.

After examining the event logs, I find that `tcl85.dll` is the library responsible for the crash.

My guess is that there is either a bug in my program which misuses the tcl api and causes tcl to enter an undefined state, eventually resulting in a crash, or there is a bug in tcl85 itself.

My question is, how can I diagnose the cause of this problem? Which tools would help get something like a backtrace on where the program is erring? I have examined the error in the windows event log, but the information there doesn't seem sufficient for identifying a cause.

Below is the xml of the event log error:

```
 Name="Application Error"></Provider>
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>100</Task>
<Keywords>0x0080000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-08-27 08:54:13"></TimeCreated>
<EventRecordID>6173</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>my.windows.8.tablet.computer</Computer>
<Security UserID=""></Security>
</System>
<EventData><Data><string>my_tkinter_app.exe</string>
<string>0.0.0.0</string>
<string>514e2c2f</string>
<string>tcl85.dll</string>
<string>8.5.2.15</string>
<string>53b1e888</string>
<string>c0000005</string>
<string>0007697f</string>
<string>1378</string>
<string>01cfc1d44828ecb0</string>
<string>C:\Users\ADMINI~1\DOWNLO~1\my_tkinter_app.exe</string>
<string>C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI35042\tcl85.dll</string>
<string>b7745a30-2dc7-11e4-9732-88124e8c7600</string>
<string></string>
<string></string>
</Data>
<Binary></Binary>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

From the `c0000005` I gather that there is an access violation, but this is still too generic to identify a cause.

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce the crash under Linux, so I am looking for a windows-specific way of tracing this issue.

Comment: I think it's hard to say. Is it an app that you wrapped yourself? Maybe the libraries that were wrapped are not suited for windows; I tried using Tclkit for instance to create an exe and there were different files to be used for different OS; and one starpack I think that was able to work on both linux and Win OS. I'm just saying that it might be something a bit similar.

Comment: It's more likely to be API misuse, _but not guaranteed_. The access violation is ___probably_ a NULL dereference__.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PDB file for the Tcl involved (e.g. because you built it yourself), the easiest way can be to simply instruct windows to safe a MiniDump when the process crashes.

The Windows Error Reporting (WER) System has the needed parts to do this, you just need to set some registry keys and find the produced .dmp file.

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the needed things:

Once you have the crash dump, you simply open it with a debugger of your choice (Visual Studio or Windbg) and start debugging, point it to your PDB files and Microsofts Symbol server and get a nice stacktrace of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical error in my Windows 7 desktop with Python 2.7.9 installed, and this turned out to be a thread safe problem in my program. I'm not sure if your problem would be fixed with my solution, just share it.

For all who runs tkinter in other(than main) thread, tkinter is **NOT THREAD SAFE**. In my program, I have to run twisted reactor in main thread, so I run tkinter UI in another thread. Since I directly called tkinter method (like `Text.insert()`) in main thread, it occasionally crash with c0000005 error.

After reading [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue11029), I modified my tkinter based UI module with:

1. Added a command queue to specific widget (Text widget, in my case)
2. Added a handler method with `after()` and `queue.get_nowait()` as below:

   ```
   def commandQueueHandler(self):
       try:
           while 1:
               your_command = self.textCommandQueue.get_nowait()
               if your_command is not None:
                   # execute the command ....
               self.Text.update_idletasks()
       except Queue.Empty:
           pass
       self.Text.after(100, self.commandQueueHandler)
   ```

   This method self-trigger every 100ms to handle the command in the queue, but you have to trigger it ***once*** to make it work. (I trigger this in `__init__`, after all widget was initialized.)

In main thread, all I have to do is just put command/message in the command queue and wait for it to be handled. Of course, there will be a little delay before the command was executed.

That's it! With this modification, my program runs no tcl c0000005 error after 2 week stress test. Hope this helps.

p.s. Be careful, only widget classes provide `after()` method, [check this page for details](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm%20[2]).

Comment: @JasonMArcher, thank you very much!  Although my specific problem (and its eventual solution) were different than this, you put me on the right track with the information about thread safety and tkinter.  (Basically, I had one reliable working program -- and a very similar one that crashed nearly every time -- and I couldn't see any substantial difference between them to ID the problem.  With the clue from your answer, I tracked it down:  the latter one was doing some extra unnecessary tkinter acrobatics in a separate thread.  Once I streamlined that out, it works perfectly.)

Answer (score 0):

This advice about Tkinter not being thread safe was spot on.
In my case, I resolved the problem in the following manner:

```
self.root.after(10, self.monitor) #sets up the queue monitor
self.root.update_idletasks() # adding this call resolved the issue for me
```